# Convert Html to XML

Tags: c#, html, xml

My assignment is to convert an html file to XML format. I'm working with C#/.NET. Any suggestions? Thanks heaps

Comment: Do you mean convert it to XHTML? Or some other XML format? Either way, did you try Googling - why couldn't you use an answer you found on Google?

Comment: HTML -> XML? HTML basically already is XML isn't it?

Comment: HTML isn't always (hardly ever?) well formed, hence why #Johan is probably trying to convert to XHTML

Answer (score 4):

I would try using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the Html. This would allow me to build either an object graph that I could output as Xml or I could use the parsed Html to output the Xml directly.

Alternatively, if you have full control of the Html and know it is XHtml compliant, you could do a simple XSL-transform on the Html to get the Xml you want. But is most cases you cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SgmlReader](https://github.com/MindTouch/SGMLReader), I personally used it couple of times and the results are impressive.

You can add it to your project as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SgmlReader/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#diffs

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[The Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f32f9aa8-84c8-4a83-8102-3a4f7db6f1a7/)

[Google Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f32f9aa8-84c8-4a83-8102-3a4f7db6f1a7/)

Hope this helped..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where I was writing out xml via Response.Write(...); with c#.  I simply needed to convert the html to an xml file.  I was able convert the file using the following:

Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

Hope this helps someone.